# DRF: Serializing data from external network request

Tags: json, django, http, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and making external network request which data isn't needed in models but pure serializers.

I make an external request to get some data from a server which returns JSON. Here is a quick snipped of it.

```
{
    "request": [
        {
            "packages": {
                "gold": [
                    {
                        "name": "Gold Package 1",
                        "value": "Gold1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Gold Package 2",
                        "value": "Gold2"
                    }
                ],
                "bronze": [
                    {
                        "name": "Bronze package 1",
                        "value": "Bronze1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Bronze Package 2",
                        "value": "Bronze2"
                    }
                ]
            }
      ]
}
```

After getting this request, I want to return data within this format.
How can this be achieved?

```
"response": [{
            "details": {
                "legacy_packages": [{
                        "name": "Gold Package 1",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Gold Package 2",
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

Comment: Please, share your `models.py`, `serializers.py` and probably your `views.py`, otherwise, there's nearly no way to help you

Comment: I don't have models for it as its not required to be saved within database. I need help constructing the serializer for it hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need serializer for this? Looks like plain code will be ok. Assuming `request` variable to be the first dictionary:

```
response = {
    'response':  [{
        "details": {
            "legacy_packages": [
                {
                    "name": package['name'],
                }
                for package in request['request'][0]['packages']['gold']

            ]
        }
    }]
 }
```

Introduce intermediate variables if needed for clarity and cleaner code.